# Accessing TabBarController on Button Press

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

I have programatically created a TabBarController with views etc. Now i want to show this TabBarController on Button Press. How do i do that? Currently i am presenting it modally but it doesn't work - throws sigtrap errors.

This is my code for the TabBarController

```
@implementation TabBarViewController

- (void) loadView
{
    HomeViewController * homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);

   // Set each tab to show an appropriate view controller
   [tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:homeViewController, homeViewController, nil]];
   [self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
   [homeViewController release];
   [tabBarController release];
}
```

This is my code for accessing this tabBarController from a Button Press event from my mainViewController -

```
 - (IBAction)quickBrowse:(UIButton *)sender
{
    TabBarViewController * tabBarController = [[TabBarViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentModalViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
    [tabBarController release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only override the method loadView if you are not using IB and if you want to create yours view manually. And when you do that you **must** assign your root view to the **view** property of UIViewController.

I believe in your case you don't need to override this method, you can use the viewDidLoad method to create your UITabBarController and store it in a variable, so when the event gets called all you need to do is pass the variable to the method presentModalViewController:animated:

Your final code would look like this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    HomeViewController * homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];

    // you can't pass the same view controller to more than one position in UITabBarController
    HomeViewController * homeViewController2 = [[HomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];

    // local variable
    self.modalTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

   // Set each tab to show an appropriate view controller
   [self.modalTabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:homeViewController, homeViewController2, nil]];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.modalTabBarController = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

 - (IBAction)quickBrowse:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self presentModalViewController:self.modalTabBarController animated:YES];
}
```